# I need to create a DrawerNavigator and the drawer should be available on one screen, not all. So, how do I go about implementing it?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So, I have got a dummy Register activity. When the user presses on TouchableOpacity, the user should be taken to a PortalListScreen which has DrawerNavigator available i.e. a drawer should be available and it needs to be toggled using a hamburger menu. I don't need the drawer on Register screen, only on PortalListScreen and subsequent screens.

I've tried everything but haven't been able to make it work.

App.js:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

import{
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation';

import Login from './components/Login';
import Register from './components/Register';
import Portal from './components/Portal';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login:
    {
      screen: Login
    },  
    Register:
    {
      screen: Register
    },
    Portal:
    {
      screen: Portal
    }
  }, 
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Register'
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends Component{
  render()
  {
    return(
      <AppContainer/>
    );
  }
}
```

Register.js:

```
export default class Register extends Component{
    render()
    {
        return(
            <View>
             <TouchableOpacity
             onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Portal')}>
                <Text>Go to portal</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>This is registration</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Portal.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TextInput
} from 'react-native';

import{
    createDrawerNavigator,
    createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import PortalListScreen from './PortalListScreen';

const PortalStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(  
    {  
        PortalStackNavigator: PortalListScreen  
    },  
    {  
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {  
            return {  
                headerLeft: (  
                    <Icon  
                        style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}  
                        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}  
                        name="md-menu"  
                        size={30}  
                    />  
                )  
            };  
        }  
    }  
);  


const PortalDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        PortalListScreen:
        {
            screen: PortalStackNavigator
        },
    }, 
    {
        initialRouteName: 'PortalListScreen'
    }
);

const PortalContainer = createAppContainer(PortalDrawer);

export default class Portal extends Component{
    render()
    {
        return(
            <PortalContainer/>
        );
    }
}
```

PortalListScreen.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';


export default class PortalListScreen extends Component{
    render()
    {
        return(
            <View>
             <TouchableOpacity
             onPress={() => this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer}>
                 <Text>Toggle drawer</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>This is PortalListScreen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Earlier by clicking on Toggle drawer, nothing was happening but now it has started giving me this error message: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication).

Comment: Do you have any file with AppRegistry -  registering your app component?

Comment: No, I don't have any file with AppRegistry. Do I need to register anything?

Comment: It's probably best to use a SwitchNavigator as your top level navigator and add a DrawerNavigator as child to that one. Your SwitchNavigator would basically contain to Screens in this case (Register screen and DrawerNavigation) and the DrawerNavigator the rest.

Comment: @Leo I have never used SwitchNavigator. Are you sure it would resolve this issue? Could you show me an example either here or on the web?

Comment: I am pretty sure that it would solve your issue. There is an example for nested navigators here: https://www.reactnativeschool.com/complex-navigation-example-with-react-navigation Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your Drawer Navigator to AppNavigator in App.js

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login:
    {
      screen: Login
    },  
    Register:
    {
      screen: Register
    },
    PortalDrawer,
  }, 
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Register'
  }
);
```